# Solving diffusion equation by taking both spatial and temporal Fourier transforms

Tags: fourier-transform, heat-equation, greens-function

One common way of finding the propagator of the diffusion equation is to Fourier transform *only* the spatial variables and then solve the resulting ODE (as it is done, e.g., in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7haZCrQDHpA&ab_channel=SteveBrunton)).
However, I was wondering if performing both spatial and temporal transformations could also be justified, as it usually makes analytical progress simpler especially in the case of (linearly) coupled diffusion PDEs (i.e. working with algebraic equations is simpler than convolutions).

The following is the derivation of 1-D diffusion kernel ( $G(x,t)= \int \frac{dq}{2\pi}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i\omega t + i q x} \tilde{G}(q,\omega)$ ):
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial t} &= D \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2} + \delta(x)\delta(t)
\rightarrow (-i\omega + D q^2) \tilde{G} = 1,\\
 G(x,t)&= \int \frac{dq}{2\pi}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i\omega t + i q x} \tilde{G}(q,\omega) = \int \frac{dq}{2\pi}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \frac{e^{-i\omega t + i q x}}{-i\omega+Dq^2}.
\end{align}
We first perform the frequency integration in the complex plane. Noting that there is one pole in the lower half plane at $\omega = -i D q^2$, the integration is zero if $t<0$ (where the contour should be closed in the upper half plane), and for $t>0$ we get:
\begin{align}
G(x,t) = \Theta(t) \int \frac{dq}{2\pi} e^{-Dq^2 t + i q x} = \Theta(t) \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 D t}}}{{\sqrt{4\pi D t}}},
\end{align}
where the Heaviside $\Theta$ enforces $G(x,t<0)=0$.

What I am wondering is whether defining $\tilde{G}$ in the first place is justified, as from the final solution it appears that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty G \, dt$ diverges, indicating one might need to use a Laplace transform instead; if it is not justified, then what is going on that this approach still gives the correct final result?

Comment: What is the difference between a Laplace transform and a one sided Fourier?

Comment: @user619894 not sure if I understand your point. I haven't taken a one-sided transform per se, the Heaviside function naturally comes out of the contour integration.

Comment: A diffusion cannot be extrapolated earlier than $t=0$ for $\delta(t)$ initial condition, so it must be set to zero for $t<0$. Effectively, this means a Laplace transform in time.

Comment: @user619894 I see, but I did not have to set anything to zero by hand, it just happened naturally because there are no frequency poles in the upper half plane. Also, note that there a divergency associated with $t \to +\infty$ as $\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$ diverges.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the decision of how to close the contour is tantamount  to deciding that the diffusion process must vanish before the singularity at $t=0$

Comment: @user619894 if I'm not mistaken, closing the contour should be such that $e^{-i\omega t}$ forces the contribution from the segment added to close the contour to vanish. For $t>0$, this means $\omega$ should have a negative imaginary part, and for $t<0$, a positive imaginary part.